# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable (Java Spark RDD)

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

Currently I learning how to use spark in java, but I hit org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable when I tried something like this example https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection

This is my code:

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 15");
Encoder<String> stringEncoder = Encoders.STRING();
Dataset<String> namesByIndexDF = sqlDF.map(new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
           @Override
           public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
               return "Name:" + row.getString(4);
           }
       }, stringEncoder);

        namesByIndexDF.show();
```

Hopefully somebody can help me. thanks!

#### Update

I fix with this code :

```
    private static MapFunction<Row, String> mapFunc(Integer idx, String name){
        return new MapFunction<Row, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Row row) throws Exception {
                return name+":"+row.get(idx);
            }
        };
    }

    public void testFunc(){
        Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Person LIMIT 15");

        //sqlDF.show();

        Encoder<String> stringEncoder = Encoders.STRING();
        Dataset<String> namesByIndexDF = sqlDF.map(mapFunc(1, "Test"), stringEncoder);
        namesByIndexDF.show();
    }
```

But can someone explain why my first code not working?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment. Could you provide more code? because this example

> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQLExample.java

works perfectly fine